# загрузка видео на хостинг

Tags: php, laravel

Почему картинки загружает нормального размера и видео по 8 байтов?

```
$video = $request->file('video');
 $fileName   = Str::slug(mb_substr($video->getClientOriginalName(), 0, 40)).'.'.$video->getClientOriginalExtension();
 Storage::disk('public')->put($path_jobs.'/video/'.$fileName, file_get_contents($video));
```

Comment: Попоробуйте сохранить через $video->saveAs(), это ведь UploadedFile

Comment: решил basename($video->getClientOriginalName())